# On the Large Cardinal Strength of Normal Moore Space Conjecture

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, large-cardinals, metric-spaces

In his seminal 1937 paper, Jones [1] proved the following result about [Moore spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)):

> **Theorem. (Jones)** If $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$ then all *separable* normal Moore spaces are metrizable.

Then he came up with the idea that maybe the *separability* condition in the above theorem could be removed. This led him to formulate the following famous conjecture:

> **Normal Moore Space Conjecture (NMSC).** All normal Moore spaces are metrizable.

Long story short, NMSC turned out to be of high large cardinal strength and so far beyond the power of $ZFC$ to decide.

In 1980, Nyikos [2] proved the consistency of NMSC using Product Measure Extension Axiom (PMEA) which is known to be consistent assuming the consistency of strongly compact cardinals. Later a more direct proof of the consistency of NMSC has been presented by Dow *et al* [3] using the stronger assumption of the consistency of supercompact cardinals.

Interestingly, Fleissner [4] used a core model argument to prove the fact that the consistency of NMSC implies the consistency of measurable cardinals as well. Thus NMSC lies between strongly compacts and measurables in the *consistency strength* order of the large cardinals hierarchy.

I wonder whether the *direct implication* power of NMSC is as strong as its large cardinal strength or not.

> **Question 1.** Does NMSC directly imply the existence of any large cardinals, say those of some topological nature such as weakly compacts? To be more precise, let me add that I look for the theorems of the form NMSC $\Rightarrow \exists \kappa$ Large (i.e. at least strongly inaccessible) if there is any.

**Update.** According to Will's answer, it turned out that NMSC doesn't contain any direct large cardinal strength.

In other direction, one may strengthen NMSC as follows:

> **Complete Normal Moore Space Conjecture (CNMSC).** All normal Moore spaces are *[completely metrizable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space)*.

Here is my second question:

> **Question 2.** Is CNMSC consistent? What are upper and lower bounds for its large cardinal strength? Strongly compacts and measurables or more?

---

**References.**

1. *Jones, F. Burton*, [**Concerning normal and completely normal spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1937-06622-5), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 43, 671-677 (1937). [ZBL0017.42902](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0017.42902).
2. *Nyikos, Peter J.*, [**A provisional solution to the normal Moore space problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2042338), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 78, 429-435 (1980). [ZBL0446.54030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0446.54030).
3. *Dow, Alan; Tall, Franklin D.; Weiss, William A. R.*, [**New proofs of the consistency of the normal Moore space conjecture. I & II**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-8641(90)90013-R), Topology Appl. 37, No. 1, 33-51 (1990). [ZBL0719.54038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0719.54038).
4. *Fleissner, William G.*, [**If all normal Moore spaces are metrizable, then there is an inner model with a measurable cardinal**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1999211), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 273, 365-373 (1982). [ZBL0498.54025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0498.54025).

Comment: Your notion of direct implication does not seem to make sense. You should probably define it precisely.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Could you please explain the issue? I mean, if there is any theorem of the form $NMSC\Rightarrow \exists \kappa$ large. Is it ok now?

Comment: What you wrote about Woodin cardinals is nonsense.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Hmmm... So there is no problem concerning the meaning of the question. Right? Let me add that by the *weakness* of Woodin cardinals in direct implication order I am pointing out to the facts such as "*the first Woodin cardinal is not even weakly compact.*" Shall I change my phrasing to mention this more explicitly? I thought it is pretty obvious.

Comment: No, it is not pretty obvious, because your notion of "direct implication" makes no sense. Sure, change the phrasing to something meaningful.

Comment: Still nonsense in what you say about Woodin cardinals.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Well, let's refrain from saying anything about Woodin cardinals which are peripheral to the main topic of this post! ;-P Yet, curious to know what you were objecting to! Maybe I was misinterpreting (or misrepresenting) the well-known facts about Woodin cardinals. If so, I will appreciate if you provide more explanations. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158098/what-is-the-shape-of-large-cardinal-tree-in-implication-strength-order) post (which includes a definition of direct implication order on large cardinal hierarchy) might be relevant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $\text{NMSC}$ is consistent, then so is $\text{NMSC}+\text{"there are no strongly inaccessible cardinals"}$.

This is because if $V \models \text{NMSC}$, then $V_\kappa \models \text{NMSC}$ for any inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$. (A proof sketch is given below.) In particular, if $\kappa$ is the first strongly inaccessible cardinal, then $V_\kappa \models \text{NMSC}+\text{"there are no strongly inaccessible cardinals"}$.

[If you think through the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(topology)) of a Moore space, it's not too hard to see that if $(X,\tau)$ is some topological space in $V_\alpha$, then the statement "$(X,\tau)$ is a normal Moore space" can be decided by looking at $V_{\alpha+\omega}$. Likewise, the fact that $(X,\tau)$ is metrizable can be decided by looking at $V_{\alpha+\omega}$. Thus the truth/falsity of the NMSC for $(X,\tau)$ is the same in $V$ and in $V_\kappa$. Because this is so for every topological space, the truth/falsity of the NMSC is the same in $V$ and in $V_\kappa$.]

Comment: (+1) Interesting observation! Thank you, Will! Any thoughts on the second question?

Comment: The answer to the second question is negative -- all metrizable spaces are normal Moore spaces, but not all metrizable spaces are completely metrizable. (The Wikipedia article I linked to in my answer mentions that all metrizable spaces are normal Moore spaces, and explains why.)

Comment: Oh I see! I glimpsed the Wiki article but somehow missed this very point! Thanks for reminding, anyway!